# Can I mask transparency of an element with CSS with its parent element?

Tags: css

So I have element1 inside element2. Element2 has a semi-transparent (opacity of 0.8) solid colour background so you can see what's behind it. element1 also has a solid colour background. I want to make it so that it has the same opacity as element2, as though with a masking effect.

If I set both their alpha channels to 0.8, you can't see the background behind element2 where element1 exists, because their opacities add up to more than 1. If I set the opacity of element1 low enough that you could see the background through it, the colour of it would be lost against element2.

Is there a way I can configure their backgrounds so that the "total opacity" of element1's background is still 0.8 and the colour of element1 is not lost except to the 0.2 loss to transparency? Sort of like if element2 was completely transparent for the parts where element2 exists.

Comment: Could you provide some [example code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to demonstrate what effect you want to achieve?

Comment: Note: "because their opacities add up to more than 1", that's not how alpha blending works. By adding 0.8 opacity over another 0.8 alpha layer you get a 0.96 alpha layer, not 1.6.

Comment: Is the transparency going to always be the same between both elements?

Comment: Edit your question to include some illustrations, please. Illustrate your desired end result, then build a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/2518285) to show us the code you've written to try to achieve that result.

Answer (score 0):

If both layers are going to have the same opacity, then you can simply wrap them in a common container and apply the opacity on that container:

```css
/* CSS checkerboard stolen from https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-4/#example-2de97f53 */
body {
  background: repeating-conic-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0deg 25%, white 0deg 50%);
  background-size: 2em 2em;
}
.wrapper {
  opacity: 0.2; /* We set the opacity on the common wrapper */
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}
/* Both layers are first drawn opaque */
.a { background: red; }
.b { background: green; top: 100px; left: 100px;}
```

```html
<div class=wrapper>
  <div class=a></div>
  <div class=b></div>
</div>
```

If they should have different opacity you'll need a bit of math: We need to find the alpha value the most transparent layer would have if the least transparent layer was opaque.

```
newAlpha = mostTransparent x (1 / leastTransparent)
```

Then we can draw that layer under the least transparent layer and set the wrapper's opacity to `leastTransparent` as we just did in the same alpha case:

```css
/* CSS checkerboard stolen from https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-4/#example-2de97f53 */
body {
  background: repeating-conic-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0deg 25%, white 0deg 50%);
  background-size: 2em 2em;
}
.wrapper {
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: relative;
  --layer1-opacity: 0.6;
  --layer2-opacity: 0.2;
  opacity: var(--layer1-opacity);
}
.wrapper div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}
.a {
  background: red;
  /* This new opacity when added to the one of the common layer
     will be equal to --layer2-opacity */
  opacity: calc(var(--layer2-opacity) * (1 / var(--layer1-opacity)));
}
.b {
  background: green;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class=wrapper>
  <div class=a></div>
  <div class=b></div>
</div>
```

But this will work only if the top-most color is the least transparent one. If you need to have the most transparent one on front, and hiding the least transparent layer, then you'd need either clipping or masking, which do require to know the shape of your elements.